# How to instantiate event listeners on new template rendered with blaze?

Tags: javascript, meteor

I've got a template being rendered by Blaze, as I have a landing page that is created, then removed when the user clicks on the signup button, where it takes it to another template that Blaze renders.

The HTML is pretty blank with just a div for the template

```
<head>
  <title>Perform</title>
</head>

<body>
<div id="template">
</div>

</body>
```

Here's a dummy first template that is loaded.

```
<template name="first">
    <button id="first_button">Click to jump to the next template</button>
</template>
```

And the second (dummy) template that gets loaded

```
<template name="second">
    <button id="second_button">This button is not wired to an event</button>
</template>
```

I have all of the Javascript loaded in one file that runs on the client:

```
var currentView;
var templateContainer;
$(document).ready(function() {

    templateContainer = document.getElementById('template');

    // This renders the first template. All events are currently working
    currentView = Blaze.render(Template.first, templateContainer);
});

Template.first.onDestroyed(function() {
    // This console.log is firing
    console.log("Destroyed first template");
});

Template.first.events({
    'click #first_button': function () {
    // Remove the first template with Blaze
    Blaze.remove(currentView);

    // Render the second template
    currentView = Blaze.render(Template.second, templateContainer);
    }
});


Template.second.onCreated(function() {
    // This console.log is firing when the 'second' template is created
    console.log("Hello! I've been created");
});
// The second template is actually a form I'd like to submit. Form omitted for brevity
Template.second.events({
    'submit #second_button': function(e, t) {
        // This console log is not firing.
        console.log("Register clicked");

    }
});
```

Anyone know what I need to do to get the 'second' template's events firing? It's just not working and it's a bit frustrating right now.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, I'm a total moron and ended up figuring this out on my own.

The click event on the second template actually works after testing and debugging, however, a submit event will not work. These are two completely different things and I'm just an idiot for not clarifying this. Apologies for the people who viewed this earlier and were confused.

Instead of:

```
Template.second.events({
'submit #second_button': function(e, t) {
    // This console log is not firing.
    console.log("Register clicked");
    }
});
```

I changed it to:

```
Template.second.events({
'submit #second_button': function(e, t) {
    // This console log is now firing
    console.log("Register clicked");
    e.preventDefault()
    return false;

    }
});
```